# Mac-mini audio out

Tags: mac-mini

I have a Mac mini (2011) which doesn't produce any sound through the audio out. I've tried with speakers, headphones, etc,... but no sounds to hear.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer on the [Apple Support pages](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1574). I assume you've made sure the sound isn't on mute and you are actually playing some music? Does their happen to be a red light in the audio output by any chance?

Comment: Do you see a prohibitory sign when you attempt to adjust the volume? Can you post a screenshot of what you see in System Preferences > Sound > Output?

Answer (score 4):

Open the **Sound Preferences Pane** in System Preferences and make sure that the settings for *output device*, *Output volume* and *Mute* are set appropriately:

[image: image of Sound Preferences Pane]

You might want to plug in a set of headphones or external speakers while this panel is open to confirm that the hardware is registering correctly.

[image: image detailing Sound Preferences pane with headphones plugged in]

If those settings all seem to be correct, Apple has a knowledgebase article: [Troubleshooting issues with no audio from built-in speakers on Macs](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1574)

I have also seen instances when the settings in the **Audio Midi Setup** panel (You'll find it in the **Utilities** folder) are incorrect. Confirm that the settings for the *Built-in Output* are 44100 Hz 2 channel-24 bit.

[image: image of Audio Midi Setup]

If all of this fails, I have seen reports of this problem having being solved by reinstalling the system software. You might want to try that before taking your computer in for repair.

Answer (score 1):

Possible issues:

- Volume set too low
- Default audio output not set correctly
- Hardware issue, go to Apple Store if possible